# Android: How can I display this bar and add icons in the toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Hello why this bar in my activity is hidden?
This is my screenshot

[image]

How can I display it? and add icons and title in the toolbar

this is my activity users.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/tb">
        </include>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:background="@color/lignt_blue"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp">
    ....
```

This is my activity users.java

```
public class Users  extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView editName;
    private ImageView imageView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.users);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String ref2 = intent.getStringExtra("ref");
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        editName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        imageView1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    }
```

this is my toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" />
```

Comment: your status bar was not hidden. It takes the color of Primarycolor defined in the color.xml or in styles.xml.

Comment: No my color is blue  <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color> with <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

Comment: can you post your entire styles xml. that could be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

From what i have researched, you have to go completely full-screen in order to alter it.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Use the below code to either remove or add the status/power bar thing(Its name escapes me):

To Hide the bar:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Or this to show the bar:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

If that isn't the problem then by the looks of the comments your status bar is taking the colour of the `colorPrimaryDark`.

To fix this i would try to use this in your styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/brand_color_dark</item>
```

OR:

Add this to the styles.xml

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/yourColor</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/yourColor</item>
```

And then remove this code from your XML file:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> 
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Give all of those methods a try and let me know if they resolve your problem.